# Can you put the Spin Connection in block diagonal form? (to be applied to the Atiyah-Singer theorem)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, spinors

I'm following the notes by Freed [about the Dirac Operator](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/DiracNotes.pdf). In section 5.4, equation (5.4.25-27), he makes the following claim about the Dirac operator. In a different notation than what he is using, he is considering the operator

$$Q = (\partial_\mu - \frac{1}{8}R_{\beta\mu\nu\sigma} \gamma^\nu \gamma^\sigma x^\beta)^2 = (\partial_\mu - \Omega_{\beta \mu} x^\beta)^2$$

so that $(\Omega_{\beta \mu}) = \frac{1}{8}R_{\beta\mu\nu\sigma} \gamma^\nu \gamma^\sigma$ is an antisymmetric matrix of Clifford algebra elements $\gamma^\mu$, in coordinates $x$ centered around the point of interest. He claims that one can write the matrix $\Omega_{\beta\mu}$ in a block diagonal form

$$\Omega_{\beta\mu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &\omega_1 &0 &0 &... &0 &0 \\
-\omega_1 &0 &0 &0 &... &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &\omega_2 &... &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &-\omega_2 &0 &... &0 &0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & &\vdots &\vdots \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &... &0 &\omega_{d/2} \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &... &-\omega_{d/2} &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where the $\omega_i$ are Clifford algebra elements. If one does this, then we can more easily find the heat kernel, since the operator splits up into smaller chunks and use it to show the Dirac operator's index gives the $\hat{A}$ genus.

My question is if such a decomposition is valid, and how one can make sense of these ideas? I've never seen the Riemann tensor decomposed like this and I couldn't find online any resources that indicate this is possible.

Comment: Is this possibly some other way of talking about using a basis made of bivectors?

Comment: Is he just using that any antisymmetric matrix can be written in block diagonal form? This is certainly true if the entries are real number. It is not so obvious to me that this remains true if the entries are elements of a Clifford algebra. (But it would not surprise me.)

Comment: That's what I was thinking @mmeent. But I don't know how to justify that statement.

Comment: @BenCrowell what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Joe, I am curious of the context of the operator $Q$. Gravitational monopoles?

Comment: @MadMax, It's an important term that shows up when you square the curved-space Dirac operator, basically the Laplacian defined on spinor fields in curved space. It comes up in the context of trying to prove the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem for Dirac operators. Exponentiating it and taking the trace with respect to the chiral matrix "$\gamma_5$" should give an expression for the $\hat{A}$ genus of the manifold. c.f. Freed's notes or my old question for context. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518012/

Comment: @Joe, the natural curved-space extention of the Dirac operator would involve an extra spin connection (rather than the Riemann tensor) WITHOUT multiplied by an extra $x^\beta$. The $x^\beta$ term in operator Q reminds me of t' Hooft's hedgehog topological configurations. It's understood that the Q operator in Freed's note is related to proving the Atiyah–Singer index theorem. Topology/homotopy comes into the picture naturally.

Comment: @MadMax there's nothing to do with monopoles here. I picked a coordinate system where the Christoffel symbols are $\Gamma_{\mu \rho \nu} = \frac{1}{2}R_{\beta \mu \nu \rho} x^\beta $ and where the tetrads $e^a_\mu$ are $\delta^a_\mu + O(|x|^2)$. Then one can show that the spin connection takes this form in these coordinates. 

This is similar to electromagnetism picking a gauge where $A_\mu = \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}x^\nu$, so that the covariant derivative becomes $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + i \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}x^\nu$. The operator above is the analog of $D_\mu D^\mu$

Comment: Isn't $A_\mu = \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}x^\nu$ a monopole configuration?

Comment: It is not. Check that $\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu = F_{\mu \nu}$ at the origin. This is nonsingular at the origin and has zero divergence, that $dF =0$. What you're probably thinking of is if the magnetic field is pointing radially outwards then that's a monopole configuration. In a monopole situation, $A_\mu$ isn't even well-defined at the origin. In fact, whenever $A_\mu$ is a locally smooth function, there can't be monopoles, since then $d d A = 0$. Feel free to message me if you have any other questions about this

Comment: Is the non-trivial topology of $R_{\beta \mu \nu \rho}$ (rather than constant $F_{\mu \nu}$) key to the proof of the Atiyah–Singer index theorem in Freed's note? I didn't read Freed's note in detail, you can educate me on this point.

Comment: The Atiyah-Singer Theorem (or this specific case of Dirac Operator) says the index of the Dirac operator (which is manifestly an integer) is something called the $\hat{A}$ genus integrated over the manifold. The theorem shows that the index is related to how twisted a spin bundle over the manifold is. The non-trivial topology of this bundle is a topological invariant of the manifold because the spin bundles are intrinsic. A-S says that the index can be computed by an integral of a smooth local form. This is simliar to the 'Dirac quantization' $\int F \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ for 2d gauge fields

Comment: If it means anything, the case of tensoring with a G-bundle (i.e. coupling to a G gauge field) can reproduce the chiral anomalies of chiral fermions coupled to gauge theories. This heat kernel method is essentially the method used by Fujikawa to compute the chiral anomaly, with the extra complication of coupling to gravity. This part I'm stuck on is the gravity part of the story.

Comment: Could you clarify if this is supposed to be for Riemannian even dimensional manifolds only? Or is pseudo-Riemannian and (or) odd dimensional cases also included?

Comment: I suppose it only really matters for even dimensional manifolds since this index only makes sense in even dimensions. But it would be nice if the logic could extend to arbitrary dimensions